# Как правильно написать с return или без?

Tags: java, android

Вот два возможных варианта написания функции, какой правильнее?

Вот первый

```
private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (!isPermissionGranted(permission)) {
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        // Check for Rationale Option
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Вот второй

```
private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (isPermissionGranted(permission)) {
        return true;
    }

    permissionsList.add(permission);
    // Check for Rationale Option
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Вопрос в дополнительном `return;` , мне больше нравиться второй вариант, так как метод читается легче и не растянут по ширине вложенными `if`...

Но где то я слышал, что дополнительные `return;` тоже не сильно хорошо...

Comment: "Правильнее" в плане стиля программирования - штука субъективная. Вот, допустим, правило правописания "тся/ться" - штука объективная. Поэтому если вы считаете, что точек выхода из функции должно быть как можно меньше - вам нужен первый вариант, да ещё и, по идее, доработанный, чтобы точка выхода была 1. Если вам нужно меньше ветвлений в коде для улучшения его читабельности - вам нужен второй вариант. И независимо от выбора правильно пишется так: "мне больше нравится".

Comment: Вопрос порождающий бессмысленный холивар. Оба варианта уместны, оба читаются нормально. Я считаю что на таких мелочах не стоит заморачиваться.

Comment: Для удобства, я например пишу в одну строку `if (isPermissionGranted(permission)) return true;` из чего вместо 3 строк получается одна. (Но это если одна задача в if, если несколько, то придется и скобки писать)

Comment: @iFr0z а я бы это написал в 4 строки (с учетом `{` на новой строке). Так что всё сводится к субъективному спору о вкусе фломастеров.

Comment: @Regent какой вопрос, такой и ответ)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В программистских кругах есть сторонники того, что у функции/метода должен быть [один return](https://habrahabr.ru/post/40841/), потому что так сказал [Эдсгер Дейкстра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0,_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5). И если они видят более одного return - у них обостряется страшная болезнь - "[в интернете кто-то не прав](http://xkcd.ru/386/)". И они, в угодну своей вере, будут уродовать код.

Но тут их поджидает другая штука. Оказывается, не все компиляторы/интерпретаторы могут делать бесконечную вложнность. К примеру, visual studio имеет [ограничение в 128 вложенных блоков](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dcda4f64.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). И приходится разбивать все на кучу мелких и бессмысленных функций.

Какой же выход? Если наступила ситуация подобна вышеуказанной и не понятно, как поступить, нужно подумать, а как будет понятнее и красивее. Я бы переписал для начала код так - условие проверки версии андроида вставил внутрь `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` (а может бы создал враппер для этого метода с проверкой версии - нужно смотреть код глубже). В результате двойной вложенный if исченет совсем. Ну где то так:

```
private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (isPermissionGranted(permission)) {
       return true;
    }
    permissionsList.add(permission);
    return shouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleWithVersionCheck(permission);
}
```

Но если пойти в угоду Дейкстре, тогда так

```
private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    bool result = false;
    if (!isPermissionGranted(permission)) {
       permissionsList.add(permission);
       result = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleWithVersionCheck(permission);
    }
    return result;   
}
```

Comment: Собственно, сторонники теории одной точки выхода на возражение про кучу неудобных вложений отвечают, что в таком случае это явно означает, что метод нужно разбить на несколько. Хотя порой удается "сторговаться" на один доп. `return` в начале метода, отвечающий за проверку входных параметров (вроде это "guard code" называется). Во всех аргументах есть смысл, но, как по мне, правильнее придерживаться здравого смысла, а не какого-то одного-единственного шаблона во всех случаях. Это как  дополнение к ответу.

Comment: собственно я об этом и написал - нужно писать так, что бы было красиво и понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вообще написал в одну строку.

```
private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    return isPermissionGranted(permission)  || 
           !permissionsList.add(permission) || 
           Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ||
           shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission);
}
```

P.S. ответ больше шутка

Comment: запись хорошая, но я вот так визуально не уверен, что оно работает идентично. Нужны тесты, тесты и ещё много тестов.